# Как программно нажать на кнопку confirm диалогового окна?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как программно нажать на кнопку confirm диалогового окна?

Я пробывал удалить , по не выходит в , не могу понять почему. Потому решил подумать может как-то можно программно нажать на кнопку диалогового окна.

```
input.eq(iinp).attr('onclick','myFunction()');
input.eq(iinp).prop('onclick',null);
input.eq(iinp).off('click');
$('html').unbind('click');
input.eq(iinp).removeAttr("onclick");
```

---

```
<input type="submit" name="fyy" value="конец" onclick="return confirm('Вы точно этого хотите?')" />
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял вопрос. Ты хочешь при появлении диалогового окна нажать ОК или открыть само диалоговое окно?

Comment: @Doofy  нужно нажать на кнопку диалогового окна - То есть , есть диалоговое окно, на котором есть кнопки. Эти кнопки не могут быть на стене у тебя в комнате.

Comment: через делфи можно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вы не можете ни стилизовать, ни как либо воздействовать на системные окна с помощью javascript из браузера.

Вам необходимо самому реализовать подобное модальное окно или воспользоваться одним из готовых решений. Например, [SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert). Он поддерживает окна с подтверждениями.

Вот пример его работы (подробнее по ссылке выше):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое, спасибо за отзывчивость, но меня не интетесует создание собственнонго диалогового окна, и все связанные с ним процесссы и опирации.

Comment: @gilo1212 способа изменить или воздействовать на системные окна нет. Это большой удар по безопасности браузера. Следовательно, ваш вопрос не решаем в принципе

Comment: Кто-то написал что можно это сделать через делфи, может вы знаете как ? Через какуй-ту билбиотеку?

Comment: @gilo1212 это не библиотека, а сторонняя программа. Нет, не знаю, но вряд ли вам нужно чтобы пользователь вместо браузера скачивал и запускал еще какую-то приблуду